# How can I listen to events on a modal created via the data api?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-events

I have a modal that is (dynamically) added to my page like this:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block modal-button in" data-target="#modal-3" href="/api/some-params" aria-hidden="false">Activate Modal</a>
```

Since this is loading from a `remote`, I'd like to listen to the remote and do some event initialization once the remote loads. However, I can't seem to bind an event to it. Here is how I am trying to do it.

```
$('.modal-button').last().on('loaded.bs.modal'), function(e){
    console.log('loaded!');
});
```

But that event never seems to fire. Can I not mix the data-api and Javascript way of initializing Bootstrap UI elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, answered my own question. It has nothing to do with how the elements are initialized by the data attributes.... the element specified in the `data-target` fires the event, not the div with the `data-toggle` attribute.

So....

```
target = $('.modal-button').last().data('target') // this returns a string
$(target).on('loaded.bs.model', function(e){
    // do stuff
});
```

works